# How to populate backbone collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

how do I populate this in my backbone view with these response

```
{
 "_count":6,
  "data":[{
            "id":"6",
            "continent":"NORTH AMERICA",
            "code":"NA",
            "sort_order":"6",
            "published":"1",
            "date_created":"2014-02-02 13:16:54",   
            "createdbypk":"1",
            "date_modified":"2014-02-02 21:17:10",
            "modifiedbypk":"1"
          },
          {
            "id":"5",
            "continent":"SOUTH AMERICA",
            "code":"SA",
            "sort_order":"5",
            "published":"1",
            "date_created":"2014-02-02 13:16:53",
            "createdbypk":"1",
            "date_modified":"2014-02-02 21:17:00",
            "modifiedbypk":"1"


      }]
 }
```

what i want is just the "data". Using this backbone code

`using this "this.model.get('_count')" will return 6
    but this one "this.model.get('continent')" will return nothing.`

Any help please

Comment: Can you post more code on how you set up your collections, models and views?

Comment: Here is the overall code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21597927/cascading-select-boxes-with-backbone-js?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the `parse` method in your collection:

```
parse: function(response){
  return response.data;
}
```

See http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse

As explained in the link, you add this in your collection definition, e.g.

```
var Continents = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: BASE_URL + 'api/continents',
    model: Continent,
    parse: function(response){
      return response.data;
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey David. this is the overall code of it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21597927/cascading-select-boxes-with-backbone-js?rq=1 Where I'm going to add the parse function?

Comment: Look at the example in his link. They give an example of a collection that gets Tweets.

Answer (score 0):

`this.model.get('data')` will return you an array of the continent objects.

so `this.model.get('data')[0].continent` should return "NORTH AMERICA"
and `this.model.get('data')[1].continent` should return "SOUTH AMERICA"